# How to filter a set of rows according to an indexed position?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am  stuck on how to filter out a set of rows based on the indexed position. For more clarity, lets have a dummy problem, lets say I have a datframe of user having multiple profile, like in example df1 i have three user John, Johnny and Ben having their multiple profile..

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"user": ["Peter (1)", "Peter (2)", "Peter (3)","John (1)","John (2)","John (3)","Johnny (1)","Johnny (2)"], "value": [1, 3, 3, 1, 6, 3, 4, 1]}, )
```

I sort the df1 based on value and reindex it

`df1=df1.sort_values(by='value', ascending=False)`

`df1.index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`

df1 looks like this

[image]

Now i am stuck as how to filter out rows for user having first indexed value (in this case John), lets say to new dataframe df2, and also to filter out rows for second indexed user (in this case Johnny) to new dataframe df3
expected df2 should look like this

[image]

df3 should look like below

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the first index value and split it and exclude last item(assuming that user name may have parenthesis), and then search for the value in the entire dataframe for that particular column.
For example:

```
firstIndexUser = df1['user'].str.split('(').str[:-1].str.join('(').iloc[0]
```

This **firstIndexUser** will have value as '**John**'
Now you can compare with against the entire dataframe to get your df2

```
df2 = df1[df1['user'].str.split('(').str[:-1].str.join('(')==firstIndexUser]
```

The output looks like this:

```
>>df2
       user  value
0  John (2)      6
4  John (3)      3
6  John (1)      1
```

If you want, you can reset the index for df2

```
>>df2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
>>df2
       user  value
0  John (2)      6
1  John (3)      3
2  John (1)      1
```

You can follow the similar approach for your df3

Comment: looks interesting..i am getting error while executing firstIndexUser  AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: You must have mistaken somewhere, str method is applicable for the pandas series, not for a string variable. I think you are doing something lke firstIndexUser.str which gives that error.

Comment: no ..i am able to execute firstIndexUser=df1.iloc[0]['user'] ..it gives John (2) ...but when i execute firstIndexUser = df1.iloc[0]['user'].str.split('(').str[:-1].str.join('(')  ..it gives Attribute error

Comment: Oh yeah, I got your point. Just place .iloc[0] to the last of the expression  in firstIndexUser. I have edited the answer you can check now.

Comment: Thats brilliant solution..i tried this approach before also, but had this attribute error ..i was looking for this solution only!! THANKS A TON..

Comment: Happy To Assist.

Answer (score 4):

After sorting the dataframe you can use [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to split the strings in the `user` column to create a grouping `key`, then `group` the dataframe on this grouping key and for each subgroup per `user` create a mapping of `user` -> `dataframe` inside a `dict` comprehension:

```
key = df1['user'].str.split().str[0]
dct = {user:grp.reset_index(drop=True) for user, grp in df1.groupby(key)}
```

Now to access the dataframe corresponding to the `user` we can simply lookup inside the dictionary:

```
>>> dct['John']

       user  value
0  John (2)      6
1  John (3)      3
2  John (1)      1

>>> dct['Peter']

        user  value
0  Peter (2)      3
1  Peter (3)      3
2  Peter (1)      1

>>> dct['Johnny']

         user  value
0  Johnny (1)      4
1  Johnny (2)      1
```

Comment: `key` is a series that is not in `df1` but its been used in grouping of `df1`...it works :) ...just wondering how this works? because of same indexes in both of them

Comment: Wow, It works! And I vote for this solution as it is most remerkable from my point of view.

Comment: if there are 100 or more users having multiple profile, this solution seems difficult

Comment: @Naveen `groupby` method can be use to `group` the dataframe/Series by `Series/ndarray/or even a list` even if its not present in the dataframe..In case a series is passed its indices are first aligned..In case of `ndarray or list` the length of the `ndarray or list` must match with the length of dataframe/series that needs to be grouped..

Comment: @ArunMenon Can you please explain in more details as to why you think its difficult?

Comment: i think @Bikhyat Adhiakri response seems to be the solution..the point is the indexed position i.e first or second position should help me to filter out

Comment: @ArunMenon So you want to only filter the rows corresponding to user indexed at position `0 and 1`?

Comment: @ArunMenon Do you need `dct = {user: df1[df1['user'].str.contains(fr'^{user.split()[0]}\b')] for user in df1.loc[[0, 1], 'user']}` ?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma i would like to have it in dataframe format

Answer (score 3):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"user": ["Peter (1)", "Peter (2)", "Peter (3)","John (1)","John (2)","John (3)","Johnny (1)","Johnny (2)"], "value": [1, 3, 3, 1, 6, 3, 4, 1]}, )

df1=df1.sort_values(by='value', ascending=False)

cols = df1.columns.tolist()
df1['name'] = df1['user'].replace(r'\s\(\d\)','',regex=True)
grp = df1.groupby(by=['name'])
dataframes = [grp.get_group(x)[cols] for x in grp.groups]

df2, df3 = dataframes[:2]  # as mentioned, we are interested just in first two users
```

`df2`:

```
       user  value
3  John (1)      1
4  John (2)      6
5  John (3)      3
```

`df3`:

```
       user    value
6  Johnny (1)      4
7  Johnny (2)      1
```

Comment: My point wassince John is indexed in first position (because of high value), i would like to only filter the first and second indexed value..peter should not come

Comment: @ArunMenon got it. I've modified the code a bit.

Answer (score 3):

First line adds a column for name  
Create a dictionary with each entry as a dataframe with key as unique name

```
df1['name']=[x.split(' ')[0] for x in df1['user']]
for nam in list(df1.name.value_counts().index):
    dct[nam] = df1[df1['name']==nam][['user','value']].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Actually i need to create a dataframe only for the user who is indexed first(John) and second (Johnny)..also in my actual requirement, i have more than 100 user each having multiple profiles, so creating dictionary for each profile is not what i am in favour ..nonetheless i liked the approach!

Answer (score 1):

I believe a good way would be to first get your key, value pairs in a dictionary (with `dict` and `zip`, and then just filter on index position using `loc`. This way you ensure you can always get back your required `dataframe` by explicitly stating the index position.

```
k = dict(zip(df.index,df['user'].apply(lambda x: x.split(' ')[0])))

{0: 'John',
 1: 'Johny',
 2: 'Peter',
 3: 'Peter',
 4: 'John',
 5: 'Peter',
 6: 'John',
 7: 'Johny'}

# position 0
k[0]
'John'

# position 1
k[1]
'Johny'

# position 2
k[2]
'Peter'
```

---

Use `index` positions `0` and `1` to get John and Johny into separate `df`

```
# John (indexed 0)
df1 = df.loc[df['user'].str.split().str[0] == k[0]] # index position 0

Out[31]: 
       user  value
0  John (2)      6
4  John (3)      3
6  John (1)      1

# Johny (indexed 1)
df2 =  df.loc[df['user'].str.split().str[0] == k[1]] # index position 1

Out[32]: 
        user  value
1  Johny (1)      4
7  Johny (2)      1
```

Comment: this is also great solution..very simple!!

Answer (score 0):

Using python basic functionality **List Comprehension** we can list out our desired data.

```
list_john = [i for i in df1.user if i[0:5] == f'John '];
list_johnny = [i for i in df1.user if i[0:5] == f'Johnny'];
```

then make two df object using above list:

```
pd.DataFrame(list_john)
pd.DataFrame(list_johnny)
```